# How can I get nice animations in a ListView when an ObservableCollection gets sorted on UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I cant get nice reorder animation in ListView - also tried overriding all the various internal transitions via the `<Transitions><TransitionsCollection>`... property. Nothing. Tried using simple .Insert/.Remove and .Move and neither works nicely.

Insert/Remove has animation for the items that happen to have been pushed around and .Move acts like a Reset on the collection.

The following code in MainPage:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<Holder> Items = new ObservableCollection<Holder>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new Holder(x)));
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;

    }

    private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private Random _random = new Random();
    private bool asc = true;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IList<Holder> temp;
        //var temp = Items.Skip(1).Union(Items.Take(1)).ToList();
        // var temp = new Holder[] { Items.ElementAt(Items.Count - 1) }.Union(Items.Take(Items.Count - 1)).ToList();
        temp = Items.OrderBy(x => _random.NextDouble()).ToList();
        // temp = asc ? Items.OrderBy(x => x.I).ToList() : Items.OrderByDescending(x => x.I).ToList();

        asc = !asc;

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Items[i] != temp[i])
            {
                // When using Move, no animation occurs at all. When using Remove/Insert, there's partial
                // animation for the items that happened to stay at the same place.
                //Items.Move(Items.IndexOf(temp[i]), i);
                Items.Remove(temp[i]);
                Items.Insert(i, new Holder(temp[i].I));
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Holder
{

    public Holder(int i)
    {
        I = i;
    }

    public string Name => "Hey hey hey " + I.ToString();

    public int I { get; private set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ((Holder)obj).I == I;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return I.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

With the following XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Content="Mix" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1"></Button>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Blue">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="20"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could tell what is the mean of `nice reorder animation`?

Comment: [`ReorderThemeTransition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/xaml-animation#list-item-changes) has been included  in the default ListView and GridView templates so you do not need to manually add these animations.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: I want the items to animate to their new locations, if they were on screen (or realized off screen) and for items that are in view but that have not been realized by the LV, to animate similarly to the Add transition animation.